# "find <path to directory> -mindepth 1 -mtime +90 -type f " command doesn't select ".war" files

Tags: shell, unix

"find  -mindepth 1 -mtime +90 -type f" command doesn't select .war files

Can some one help me with the command, I want the command need to select .war files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you want to search inside *.war files.

```
find . -name \*.war -exec sh -c 'printf "\n\nFile: {}"; unzip -l {}' ";" | less +/your_search_string_here
```

Comment: Thank you @Joao Vitorino for response. I would like the command to list the *.war files as well which are older than 90 days. The command I mentioned gives all files like '.properties, .log, .html, .jsp' , etc,. but not *.war files. So, help me with a command that will list *.war files as well along with all other files.